# React app hosted on Express not routed correctly through Apache ProxyPass

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, express, proxypass

I'm trying to route traffic through so that when you get http://example.com/expressApp it goes to "/" of my Express app, hosted on AWS at port 8002. This then serves static React files in /build. However, when loading, the page is blank and nothing in the /static folder is being recognized. I've looked over a lot of similar answers on here, but none of those solutions worked for me (or maybe I've implemented it wrong?).

If I go to http://example.com/expressApp/index.html, the index loads properly, but when submitting the form, the route /api/submitForm is not found.

I have the following relevant code:

server.js (express) middleware:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/asset_images')));
app.use(express.static('build'));
app.use('/', require('./routes'));
```

routes.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

// Home page

router.get("/", function(req, res) {

  console.log("Reached the webpage!");
  const index = '/build/index.html';
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/build/index.html', {}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err: ", err);
    }
  });
});


router.post("/api/submitForm", function(req, res) {

    // does some work here


    res.status(200).send(result);

  }).catch((message) => {
    console.log("failure :(");
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Apache ProxyPass config:

```
ProxyPass "/expressApp" "http://example.com:8002"
ProxyPassReverse "/expressApp" "http://example.com:8002"
```

Project structure:

```
- express
 -- build
   --- static
   ---- css
   ---- js
  --- index.html
  --- manifest.json
 ...
```

Error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2.caa79129.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2.cf14c61d.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.50aa165f.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2.caa79129.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
main.49254150.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```